# Is $X\cup M_f$ homotopic to $B \cup _{f} X$ if $f : A\subset X → B$ is surjective?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

$X,A,B$ are topological space. $A$ is a subspace of $X$. Map $f : A → B$ is a surjective and continuous map, 
the [attaching space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_space) is 
$$B \cup _{f} X=(B\amalg X)/\{f(A)\sim A\}$$ 
Certainly in this case the attaching space is the quotient space $X/f$.

The [mapping cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cylinder)  is 
$${\displaystyle M_f=([0,1]\times A)\cup _{f}B}$$

My question is :

1. Is $X\cup M_f$ homotopic to $B \cup _{f} X$?
2. If yes, how to prove? If no, what's the counterexample? And which other requirements do we need  to make above true?

Comment: Yes, in the CW category; no in general.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks. How to prove?